# Growth of cocycles in higher degrees

Tags: gr.group-theory, unitary-representations

Let $G$ be a group with finite symmetric generating set $S$ and
let $\pi:G\rightarrow\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{H})$ be a unitary representation
of $G$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. A 1-cocycle with coefficients
in $\mathcal{H}$ (i.e. a function $b:G\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ with
$b(gh)=\pi(g)b(h)+b(g)$ for all $g,h\in G$) has at most linear growth,
meaning that $\Vert b(g)\Vert\leq Cl(g)$ for a constant $C>0$. Here
$l$ denotes the word length of $S$. The statement easily follows
from the cocycle condition in combination with the fact that $\pi$
is isometric. I am wondering whether an analogue of this also holds
in higher degrees. For example, a 2-cocycle is a function $b:G\times G\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$
with $\pi(x)b(y,z)-b(xy,z)+b(x,yz)-b(x,y)=0$. Is it possible to say
anything about the norm of $b$ in terms of the word length function
on $G$? What about higher degrees?

Comment: I don't think so: just check what happens for the trivial 1-dim rep of $\mathbf{Z}$ and a 2-coboundary.